# Failure running WebSharper 4.0 tutorial

Tags: f#, websharper

I am learning how to use WebSharper.  Actually, I am failing to learn how to use WebSharper.

I wanted to learn how to build a simple SPA so I followed [this tutorial from the WebSharper page](http://www.websharper.com/docs#getting_started/how_to_run_f-sharp_examples/heading-1).  I am able to create the SPA with Visual Studio and `Zafir` (the codename for WebSharper 4.0 that is in beta).  I followed every step in the tutorial.  I have created a [repo on github that is everything in the SPA.](https://github.com/stevenranney/basicSpa)

**The project won't build.**  More specifically, in the [`Client.fs` file](https://github.com/stevenranney/basicSpa/blob/master/basicSpa/Client.fs), I get compiler error

```
The value or constructor P is not found
```

in line 10 with the `P`, in line 11 the same error with the `Div`, and in line 18 I get the error

```
Namesapces cannot contain values.  Consider using a module to hold your value declrations.
```

with `Run()`, yet when I try to move the `[<SPAEntryPoint>]` information into the `module HelloWorld`, I get the error

```
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point.  A type annotation...
```

As a result, when I try to build this project, the build fails.

Why am I getting these errors?  Is the tutorial out of date with the rest of WebSharper?  What can I do to get a simple tutorial to work correctly?

EDIT: I get the same errors when I use WebSharper v3.*x*, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not mentioned in the tutorial, adding

```
open WebSharper.Html.Server
```

eliminated the compiler errors with `P` and `Div`, adding

```
open WebSharper.Html.Client
```

eliminated a new compiler error of `OnClick`, and moving the `[<SPAEntryPoint>]` into the module eliminated that compiler error and allowed me to build the project.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report! I have updated documentation, indeed that page was not updated since a while. I will review it more thoroughly.

The source of the documentations are found at https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper.docs, feel free to add issue there about further questions/problems or also you can submit a PR.